# SCons building project in debug mode uses /MD runtime instead of /MDd runtime

Tags: godot, scons, microsoft-runtime-library

I have downloaded Godot's cpp bindings and I'm building the library from source using SCons (it comes with an SConstruct file). However, when I use this library from a project in Visual Studio, I get a linker error due to the debug library built using SCons using the /MD runtime instead of the /MDd runtime that debug projects use in MSVC.

Is there a way of telling SCons which runtime it should use?

Comment: Which versions of the following are you using: Python, SCons, Visual studio, Godot, Windows?